# MongoDB Aggregate - $sum arguments

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following aggregation query:

```
{"$match": {"expired":{"$exists":False}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$retailer",
    "average_price": {"$avg":"$price"},
    "highest_price": {"$max":"$price"},
    "lowest_price": {"$min":"$price"},
    "online": {"$sum":1}
}}
```

I want to expand on this by counting how many products are on promotion. I tried this (which is obviously not valid):

```
{"$match": {"expired":{"$exists":False}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$retailer",
    "average_price": {"$avg":"$price"},
    "highest_price": {"$max":"$price"},
    "lowest_price": {"$min":"$price"},
    "online": {"$sum":1},
    "promomtion": {"$sum":{"promotion":True}},
}}
```

Is there a way of computing this promotion count from within this query?

Comment: Project a `promotion_c:{$cond:[{$eq:{'$promotion':true}},1,0]}` then sum up `promotion_c`

Answer (score 2):

Solved this with:

```
{"$match": {"expired":{"$exists":False}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$retailer",
    "average_price": {"$avg":"$price"},
    "highest_price": {"$max":"$price"},
    "lowest_price": {"$min":"$price"},
    "online": {"$sum":1},
    "promotion_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$promotion", True ] }, 1,0 ] }}
}}
```